# Issues with function context in Office Scripts

Tags: javascript, typescript, office-scripts

I am having an issue calling a function into the main script whilst maintaining the excel context

`async function main(context: Excel.RequestContext){
findMD(1)
}`

The function `findMD(test)` contains various ranges which draw from `context.workbook` and due to the function being defined outside of `main` I'm getting a `cannot find name 'context'` error.
To try and solve this I changed  `function findMD(test){` to `async function findMD(context: Excel.RequestContext,test){`. However whilst it has solved the context errors I can still not run the script because the function call `findMD(1)` is now getting an error message of `Expected 2 arguments but got 1`

Would seriously appreciate any assistance one could offer as this is killing me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the findMD() function to take context as an input parameter, you also need to supply that parameter whenever you call it. Here is an example of a helper function which takes as input the context object, as well as a second parameter, much like what you are attempting to do.

```
async function helper(context: Excel.RequestContext, test) {
  let workbook = context.workbook; 
  let worksheets = workbook.worksheets;
  let selectedSheet = worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

  selectedSheet.load("name");
  await context.sync();

  console.log( selectedSheet.name);
  console.log( test);
}

async function main(context: Excel.RequestContext) {
  helper(context,"test parameter");
}
```

Inside of main(), when I call helper(), I pass in both the context object, as well as the value for the test parameter which I want the function to see.